# Get random rows on datatable

Tags: c#, random

I want to get random 05 rows on the dataTable in C# with the information as following:

[image]

I has been use the solution to Clone belong to other dt and used Random function to process but can't successful. Please help to advise for me to resolve this issue.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What have you tried and what was the issue?

Comment: get the count of rows, get a random number in between 0 and this number as id, repeat five times. Only works if you have guaranteed consecutive IDs

Comment: @TimSchmelter I want to get random 05 rows from the dataTable as above but don't successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you havent shown your code we can't fix it, however:

```
Random r = new Random();
var rowsTaken = new HashSet<int>();
DataTable rndTable = yourDataTable.Clone();
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    int rndRowIndex = r.Next(yourDataTable.Rows.Count);
    while(!rowsTaken.Add(rndRowIndex))
        rndRowIndex = r.Next(yourDataTable.Rows.Count);
    DataRow randomRow = yourDataTable.Rows[rndRowIndex];
    rndTable.ImportRow(randomRow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a random number between 0 and number of rows and blance between to results like this you can't get the same number twice .

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable()
Random rnd = new Random();

int row1= rnd.Next(0, dt.Count); 
int row2= rnd.Next(0, row1-1);    
int row3= rnd.Next(row2+1,row1-1);     
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

`dataTable.OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(5)`

Or

`var random = new Random();`

`dataTable.OrderBy(x => random.Next()).Take(5)`